# How to write a test for bundle which it depends on some entity

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony5

I've been working on a grid bundle for Symfony. The bundle receives a Symfony Entity and based on that, it renders a gridview.

something like this:

```php
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct(GridBuilder $grid, BookGrid $userGrid)
    {
        $this->grid = $grid;
        $this->userGrid = $userGrid;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'grid' => $this->grid->build($this->userGrid),
        ]);
    }

}
```

`BookGrid` is a class extended from `BaseGridConfigurator` which it has to implement `getEntity` method:

```php
class BookGrid extends BaseGridConfigurator
{

    public function getEntity()
    {
        return Book::class;
    }

}
```

The GridBuilder uses the EntityRepository (in this case BookRepository) to get the entity's metadata such as fields, Repository and QueryBuilder.

If I want to write unit test for the bundle, I need an entity class to pass it to GridBuilder. I think there are two approaches to solve this problem.

1. Create a mock Entity and Repository
2. Create a real Entity and Repository class inside my test directory

My question is which approach is correct? and is there any other way to test a bundle that it depends on an entity?

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a "correct" approach here. Take the one that is working for you best

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `getEntity` (which perhaps should be renamed to `getEntityClass`) is used by `GridBuilder` to obtain the desired entity repository from the entity manager internally, wouldn't it be easier to have `BaseGridConfigurator` provide access to the entity repository directly? E.g. `getEntityRepository(): EntityRepository` instead of `getEntity(): string`. I can imagine this would significantly reduce the amount of mocking you would have to do if all you need is the entity repository.

In any case, the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#mocking-a-doctrine-repository-in-unit-tests) on the subject of unit testing entity repositories advice against unit testing entity repository dependent implementations in general.

But if you have to, I would focus on a design where your implementation needs as few contact points with the entity repository as possible in order to minimize the amount of mocking that the test requires. But would still opt for mocking over stubbing regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, it doesn't make any difference if I ask access to the `Repo` class. In that case also I need to create mock or stub for the repository which I will face the same challenge.